# Array not printing properly

Tags: java, netbeans

Why does the array "prevScore" not print the value "points"?

I want it to print out points for `prevScore [0]`, and then `null 0`

This is the array, after the // is something I thought I could use.

```
int [] prevScore = new int[10]; //{ 0 };

String [] prevScoreName = new String[10]; //{"John Doe"};

public static int[] scoreChange (int prevScore[], int points)
{
     for(int i = 9; i > 0; i--){
     prevScore[i] = prevScore[i-1];
     }
     prevScore[0]= points;

     return prevScore;
}
```

I dont know if the print of prevScore is needed.

```
//a method that prints high scores
public static void printScores (int prevScore[], String prevScoreName[])  
    {
         for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--){
            System.out.println(prevScore[i] + " " + prevScoreName[i]);
          }
 }
```

Here is the rest of my program I am working on... currently only i get one, 0 John Doe.

```
 public class Main

{
static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in)); // user input


public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
 {
   int press = 0;

    do   {
       int menuchoice = 0;
       int [] prevScore = new int[] { 0 };

       String [] prevScoreName = new String[] {"John Doe"};


   System.out.println("Menu choice: 1 to start game, 2  print instructions,"
                + "3 prev score");
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int userinput = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

   int points;
   menuchoice = userinput;

       if (menuchoice == 1){
       points = startGame();
       String newName = endGame(points);
       prevScore = scoreChange(prevScore,points);
       prevScoreName = nameChange(prevScoreName, newName);
        }
        if (menuchoice == 2){
        printInstructions();
        }
        if(menuchoice == 3) {
       printScores(prevScore, prevScoreName); }
        if (menuchoice != 1 && menuchoice != 2 && menuchoice !=3 ) {
       System.out.println("ERROR"); }

    } while (press !=4 );
} 

//a method that initializes a new game
public static int startGame () throws IOException //a method that initializes a new game
{

    int lives = 3;
    int points = 0;

    System.out.println("Good Luck!");

do {

    System.out.println("Points: " + points);
    System.out.println("Lives: " + lives);

    int correct = displayNewQuestion();

    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(userinput.nextLine());

    if (userAnswer == correct){
        points ++;
        System.out.println("Correct");
    }
    if (userAnswer != correct ){
        lives --;
        System.out.println("Incorrect");
    }
} while (lives > 0);

    return points;
}

public static String endGame (int points) throws IOException // a method that tells the user the game is over
{
System.out.println("GAME OVER");

    Scanner nameinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your name for the score charts!");
    String newName = nameinput.next();

return newName;
}

public static int[] scoreChange (int prevScore[], int points)
{
// for(int i = 0; i < 10; i--){
      //  prevScore[i] = prevScore[i-1];
   // }
    // prevScore[1]= prevScore[0];
     prevScore[0]= points;

    return prevScore;
}

public static String[] nameChange (String prevScoreName[], String newName)
{

    /*for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        prevScoreName[i] = prevScoreName[i-1];
    }
    //prevScoreName[1] = prevScoreName[0];*/
    prevScoreName[0] = newName;

    return prevScoreName;

 }
public static void printInstructions ()  //a method that will print the instructions to the user
{
System.out.println("Instructions");
}


public static void printScores (int prevScore[], String prevScoreName[])  //a method that prints high scores
{

  /*  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i--){
    System.out.println(prevScore[i] + " " + prevScoreName[i]);
   }*/

     for (int i = prevScore.length; i > 0; i--){
     System.out.println(prevScore[i-1] + " " + prevScoreName[i-1]);

    }
 }
public static int displayNewQuestion ()  // a method that displays a random arithmetic question
{
    int  correctAnswer = 0;

    int num1 = randInt (12,-12);
    int num2 = randInt(12, -12);

    Random rand = new Random();
    int operator = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;

    if (operator == 1)
    {
        System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2);
        correctAnswer = num1 + num2;
    }
    if (operator == 2)
    {
        System.out.println(num1 + " - " + num2);
        correctAnswer= num1 - num2;
    }
    if (operator == 3)
    {
        System.out.println(num1 + " x " + num2);
        correctAnswer= num1*num2;
    }
    if (operator == 4)
    {
        if (num2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(num1*num2 + " / " + num1);
        correctAnswer= ((num1*num2)/num1);
        }
        if (num2 != 0) {
        System.out.println(num1*num2 + " / " + num2);
        correctAnswer= ((num1*num2)/num2);
    }
    }

    return correctAnswer;
}

public static int randInt(int max , int min) {

Random rand = new Random();
min = -12;
max = 12;

int randnum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

return randnum;



}

}
```

Comment: your prevScore  array does not have anything inside yet, you just declared it. **it is very unclear what you are asking** In you for loop,  for(int i = 9; i > 0; i--){ you missed out the first index which is zero

Comment: printScores() should be giving you an error?

Comment: You're also *shadowing* both of your field names in your functions, which is suspicious at best.

Comment: I honestly dont know what i am doing wrong, i just want the 10 recent list to print the name and points of the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this loop:

```
 for (int i = prevScore.length; i > 0; i--){
    System.out.println(prevScore[i-1] + " " + prevScoreName[i-1]);

}
```

I think it should solve your problem.

## Update

based on your updated program. Move the following code above the start of the 'do' loop.

```
    int [] prevScore = new int[] { 0 };

   String [] prevScoreName = new String[] {"John Doe"};
```

That is you are moving these lines out of the loop. It should work now.

That is the start of your 'main' method should look something like this:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int press = 0;
        int[] prevScore = new int[] { 0 };

        String[] prevScoreName = new String[] { "John Doe" };
        do {
            int menuchoice = 0;

            System.out.println("Menu choice: 1 to start game, 2  print instructions," + "3 prev score");
```

Comment: does this show the points?

Comment: @Adam Yes it does for me. But of course you have not provided the method that actually calls both the provided methods so I can say how it will work for you.

Comment: i posted the rest of my program with your edits

Comment: @Adam check out the updated answer. I could get the points correctly on my machine. But I dont know what other problems your code may have.

Comment: OH okay, i see it now. The other problem is that i want my the previous player's name and points shown along with the other recent playing players

Comment: for example Adam 0 (new line) Bob 0 (new line) Owaism 0--- three ppl have played this program

Comment: for example Adam 0 (new line) Bob 0 (new line) Owaism 0--- three ppl have played this program  @owaism

Comment: @Adam I hope the solution provided answer to your problem. You program has multiple problems. For example you have not given size for your arrays. Your array shift logics are incorrect. You should be using ArrayList rather than arrays in your case. Or you need to implement a counter to see how many ppl have attempted your game. Anyway outside the purview of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `printScore()` method is trying to access element [10] of an array whose index range is 0 - 9, and is never accessing element [0]. You may want to print the most recent score first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Or conversely, to print the most recent score last:

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Comment: Do i still keep prevScore[i] = prevScore[i-1];?

Comment: @Adam you have pen and paper, try to write it down you will see you gonna go out of the boundry and your code will through an exception.

Comment: @Adam if you are using my loop then you have to use i-1 but if you are using loop in this answer than you have to stick with i.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you so much! It Works! The only problem still is that the scorelist prints backwards.

```
public class Main
{
    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in)); // user input

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int press = 0;
        int[] prevScore = new int[10];

        String[] prevScoreName = new String[10];
        do {
            int menuchoice = 0;

            System.out.println("Menu choice: 1 to start game, 2  print instructions,"
                    + "3 prev score");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int userinput = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

            int points;
            menuchoice = userinput;

            if (menuchoice == 1) {
                points = startGame();
                String newName = endGame(points);
                prevScore = scoreChange(prevScore,points);
                prevScoreName = nameChange(prevScoreName, newName);
            }
            if (menuchoice == 2) {
                printInstructions();
            }
            if(menuchoice == 3) {
                printScores(prevScore, prevScoreName);
            }
            if (menuchoice != 1 && menuchoice != 2 && menuchoice !=3 ) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
        } while (press !=4 );
    }

    //a method that initializes a new game
    public static int startGame () throws IOException //a method that initializes a new game
    {

        int lives = 3;
        int points = 0;

        System.out.println("Good Luck!");

        do {

            System.out.println("Points: " + points);
            System.out.println("Lives: " + lives);

            int correct = displayNewQuestion();

            Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
            int userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(userinput.nextLine());

            if (userAnswer == correct) {
                points ++;
                System.out.println("Correct");
            }
            if (userAnswer != correct ) {
                lives --;
                System.out.println("Incorrect");
            }
        } while (lives > 0);

        return points;
    }

    public static String endGame (int points) throws IOException // a method that tells the user the game is over
    {
        System.out.println("GAME OVER");

        Scanner nameinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name for the score charts!");
        String newName = nameinput.next();

        return newName;
    }

    public static int[] scoreChange (int prevScore[], int points)
    {
        // for(int i = 0; i < 10; i--){
        //     prevScore[i] = prevScore[i-1];
        // }
        // prevScore[1]= prevScore[0];
        prevScore[0]= points;

        return prevScore;
    }

    public static String[] nameChange (String prevScoreName[], String newName)
    {

        /*for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            prevScoreName[i] = prevScoreName[i-1];
        }
        //prevScoreName[1] = prevScoreName[0];*/
        prevScoreName[0] = newName;

        return prevScoreName;
    }

    public static void printInstructions ()  //a method that will print the instructions to the user
    {
        System.out.println("Instructions");
    }

    public static void printScores (int prevScore[], String prevScoreName[])  //a method that prints high scores
    {

      /*  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i--){
        System.out.println(prevScore[i] + " " + prevScoreName[i]);
       }*/
         System.out.println("Scores: ");
         for (int i = prevScore.length; i > 0; i--){
             System.out.println(prevScore[i-1] + " " + prevScoreName[i-1]);
         }
    }

    public static int displayNewQuestion ()  // a method that displays a random arithmetic question
    {
        int  correctAnswer = 0;

        int num1 = randInt (12,-12);
        int num2 = randInt(12, -12);

        Random rand = new Random();
        int operator = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;

        if (operator == 1)
        {
            System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2);
            correctAnswer = num1 + num2;
        }
        if (operator == 2)
        {
            System.out.println(num1 + " - " + num2);
            correctAnswer= num1 - num2;
        }
        if (operator == 3)
        {
            System.out.println(num1 + " x " + num2);
            correctAnswer= num1*num2;
        }
        if (operator == 4)
        {
            if (num2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(num1*num2 + " / " + num1);
                correctAnswer= ((num1*num2)/num1);
            }
            if (num2 != 0) {
                System.out.println(num1*num2 + " / " + num2);
                correctAnswer= ((num1*num2)/num2);
            }
        }

        return correctAnswer;
    }

    public static int randInt(int max , int min) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        min = -12;
        max = 12;

        int randnum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randnum;
    }
}
```